# Does anyone know how to get the Browser ID when using the python package 'youtubemusicapi'?

Tags: python, youtube

I am currently trying to use the YouTube music API for Python called "ytmusicapi" and am stuck on how I am supposed to get the browser id. I am wondering if anyone has a fix?

I have tried to follow exactly what the docs say and also tried to search up any past solutions.